# jQuery/Ajax/Php/Mysql Fluid Random Image Carousel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, delay

I don't even really know where to start, because I have looked everywhere and can't find a darn thing. Would really appreciate any direction you can supply on this matter.

So:

What I am looking to do is load 10,000 lines of mysql (image names) into an array and display them every 10 milliseconds from the top left of the screen, and when it gets to the last one, it automatically starts over again.  I have supplied a link to an example of what someone else is doing, but they are using an API in realtime from instagram. Anyways, let me know if anyone has any ideas, I'm finding this difficult.

http://saopaulo-now.jit.su/

I also ideally want to be able to hover over to launch mini-video and show enlarged picture as well, but I need to figure out the actual functioning of the image array first lol.

Comment: check [this!](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55)

Comment: Use Twitter bootstrap? That is your answer, seriously? omg.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap isn't a bad idea.  I'm using the bootstrap-carousel to do an image area that swaps images.

it's not tough to use and you can alter how you access it.  For that many images I'd probably use ajax to pull up the images and have my controller return the image with the current index (+1) to iterate through them all.

lots of variations of how you could implement and there are other carousel plugins you could use - bootstraps seems pretty tight.

here's a gist to help with some samples:
https://gist.github.com/3471760

nothing too fancy.  good luck